Pgbouncer: Transactions not committed
We are building a multi-tenant spring boot application with pgbouncer as the middleware connection pooler and PostgreSQL as our database. We are facing an issue with pgbouncer( specifically bitnami pgbouncer) where transactions are unable to commit randomly. The error message is - "Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection". At similar timestamp, we are seeing this log from pgbouncer - "client disconnect while server was not ready". Apart from this, we are not seeing any detail from pgbouncer.
Here is the pgbouncer configuration:
[databases]
*=host={DB-HOST} port={DB-PWD} auth_user={DB-USER}

[pgbouncer]
listen_port=6432
listen_addr=0.0.0.0
unix_socket_dir=/tmp/
unix_socket_mode=0777
auth_file=/opt/bitnami/pgbouncer/conf/userlist.txt
auth_type=md5
auth_query=SELECT usename, passwd FROM user_search($1)
pidfile=/opt/bitnami/pgbouncer/tmp/pgbouncer.pid
logfile=/opt/bitnami/pgbouncer/logs/pgbouncer.log
admin_users={DB-USER}
client_tls_sslmode=disable
server_tls_sslmode=disable
pool_mode=transaction
max_db_connections=10
server_idle_timeout=900
default_pool_size=5
min_pool_size=0
reserve_pool_size=0
reserve_pool_timeout=15
ignore_startup_parameters=extra_float_digits,search_path
log_connections=1
log_disconnections=1
log_pooler_errors=1
log_stats=1
stats_period=60
server_round_robin=0
server_fast_close=0
server_lifetime=900

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance
Tried the following things:

Made pgbouncer run in a single instance
Changed the pool size per database to 5 and then 10
Reduced the reserve and min pool size from 10 to 0


This sounds to me like a network glitch, where both sides think the other side hung up on them.

shouldn't it have failed for all transactions then. Currently, it is random
